# Can someone explain me the functionality of the Assembly Class to me?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, runtime, .net-assembly

I want to Load and Create Assemblies during runtime and someone told me to use the Namespace System.Reflection.Assembly and System.Reflection.Emit.

Only reference I found was on the msdn, but it´s not as good to work with it when you don´t know where and how to start. I already googled but I didn´t find any useful tutorials/samples/references.

Can someone explain the functionality to me or give me some samples/tutorials?

Comment: Can you say why you want to load assemblies?  Other technologies might offer a better approach.  Once you load an assembly you will not be unable to unload it, if you aren't clever in the way you load it you will lock the file on disk.  there are many gotcha's, start with why and let people suggest the mechanism.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Can´t you read? The reference on msdn isn´t that good when you don´t know where and how to start handling this...

Comment: What you are probably asking is this : I would like to be able to load an assembly and create an instance of a given type in it.

Comment: @Paedow: did you scroll down towards the end of that msdn article? There's some introductory text and an example that look quite good actually.

Comment: @MikeMiller: I want to use the assembly class to dynamically generate a plugin library which got written on harddrive so my client may upload it to an archive on my ftp server and another client may browse the ftp archive and download the plugins which are then loaded during runtime

Comment: @MikeMiller: Yeah, that´s probably what i want... I never had to handle something likke this so I don´t know how it works but this could be what I´m searching

Comment: @Surfbutler: Yes, I knw where the examples on msdn sites are but it isn´t helpful for me -.-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saf5ce06.aspx

```
 public static void CompileScript(string source)
        {
            CompilerParameters parms = new CompilerParameters();
            parms.GenerateExecutable = true;
            parms.GenerateInMemory = true;
            parms.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
            parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
            // Add whatever references you might need here 
            CodeDomProvider compiler = CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
            CompilerResults results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parms, source);
            file.move(results.CompiledAssembly.Location,"c:\myassembly.dll");
        }
```

Comment: Ok, thats a good thing, but how may I get the assembly as dll-file on my harddrive?

Comment: You can flip the GenerateInMemory to false then on the CompilerResults Class there is a location it will be in a temp folder you can rename it and move it to wherever you want to

Comment: Ok, that is what I wanted... Could you edit the Question so it fits to your answer, please?

Comment: if you want to unload the same assembly you will need to load it in another app pool

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to create assembly from a source file(s) is simply run CSC (C# command line compiler) passing in source files and references as arguments. Manual IL generation is likely way too advanced, especially if you want to build assemblies from code provided by someone else.

To load - use Assembly.Load.

Comment: But is this also possible programmatical

Comment: @Paedow, sure - check out Process.Start. Micah Armantrout (+1) answer is better.