# Is it possible to write a Batch to C# Compiler?

Tags: c#, batch-file

Can someone tell me, if it is possible to write a batch to c# compiler?
And what is required or recommended for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the assembly namespace and the csharpprovider namespace.
link here: [MSDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680576/can-someone-explain-me-the-functionality-of-the-assembly-class-to-me)